# Getting a string from a jsp to create another jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, textarea

Is there a way to get a string from a textarea, for example, from a jsp , and then , when I click on a button, send that string to a controller , which uses that string in a method which in turn returns a query in list form based on that string and then display another jsp with this list.

I've tried this so far:

```
<form:form method="post" action="UserContracts" commandName="somedata" >
<table>
<tr>
    <td><h3 style="color:#0080ff;">Enter CNP :</h3></td>
    <td><form:input path="cnp" /></td>
<tr>
    <td colspan = "2"><input name="cnp" type="text"/></td>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Find" class="button" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
@RequestMapping("/uc")
public String userContract(@ModelAttribute("somedata") String cnp,HttpServletRequest request, Model model) 
{   

    List<Contract> ContractList = new ArrayList<Contract>();

    ContractList = cl.getContractsOfUser(cnp);

    model.addAttribute("ContractList", ContractList);
    System.out.println("In uc");
    return "UserContracts";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in the end.

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/uc")
> public String userContracts(@RequestParam("nr") String nr, Model model)
> {
>   List<Contract> ContractList = new ArrayList<Contract>();
>
>   ContractList = cl.getContractsOfUser(nr);
>   model.addAttribute("ContractList", ContractList);
>     System.out.println("In uc");
>     return "UserContracts";
> }
> ```

```
<table>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/VR/uc.html">
<tr><td>
<h3 style="color:#0080ff;">Enter CNP :</h3>
<tr><td>
<input name="nr" type="text">
<tr><td align="center">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute indicates the backend endpoint that will process that form. In your case you have placed "UserContracts", however you are mapping the method userContract to "/uc". These must match in order for the request to hit that controller, either change the form action or the endpoint url so they are they same.

Comment: Hi. I've made the change but nothing happens when I hit the Find button. Any ideeas?

Comment: 1 - Have you tried using a regular form? that is instead of:
<form:form method="post" action="UserContracts" commandName="somedata" >
do:
<form method="post" action="uc">  
2 - Did you remember to close the <form tag? I noticed you open both the form and the table tag but do not close them.  
3 - What happens when you type localhost/uc on the browser? (remember to adjust localhost to whatever is your server, you might have to add a port there as well if using Tomcat, that'd be localhost:8080/uc for instance).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since posting I've resolved the issue.